# How display button across then down android Xamarin native App

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

We are trying below buttons to appear across then down but no luck we also tried using mvxgridview but still no luck.

It would be great help if any help on the same. our design in AXML as we uses MVVMCross framework in Xamarin to develop.

Our expected result

Button 1  Button 2

Button 3 Button 4

Button 5 Button 6

We are expecting above dynamic list, in this case any button option may be not selected by that user then it should take immediate next button to fill that space

e.g

Button 1  Button 2

Button 4 Button 5

Button 6 Button 7

you can see above example don't have button 3 option it mean that user don't need it so that dynamically displyed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Collectionview like:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">

<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
   <Button Text="{Binding btnText}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

so you can deal with **Buttons** to add or remove the display item.

Comment: Adrain, Thanks for Answer but we are looking Android AXML native solution, this seems to be XAML

Comment: how about gridlayout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-layout